# How to run Appsync Subscriptions on graphql playground

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, graphql-subscriptions

I have deployed the graphql API on aws using the appsync service. I am able to run queries, mutation, and subscription on amazon console but when I am trying to test subscription on any graphql playground, its shows error.

I have used **serverless graphql-playground** command to run playground for AppSync.

How can I run appsync subscriptions on graphql playground?

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk27N.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol that AppSync uses for subscriptions is slightly incompatible with the protocol used in GraphQL Playground. Since Playground is open source, it would be possible for you to build support into it. But it won't work directly as-is.